# QIcon::addFile execute too slowly when Qt application startup

Tags: qt

My computer is MacBook Pro 2016 with Retina screen. It's too slowly when I use QIcon::addFile function first time during the application startup. The execute time is more than 80ms.The pictures size are 24*24 and 48*48. I know addFile function can automatically loaded high resolution version image when   the @2x file exists. I want to know what had done when addFile execute. My Qt version is Qt 5.9.1.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    Q_INIT_RESOURCE(imagetest);
    QIcon icon;
    QTime time;
    time.start();
    icon.addFile(":/new/images/iamges/navigation-panel_c.png");
    qDebug() << "time" << time.elapsed();
}
```

Comment: I/O depends not only of CPU, but also of hard drive facilities. What elapsed time do you get when doing this when the application is already started. If it really only during application startup (which I really doubt), then `#include <QShowEvent>` and re-implement the virtual function `void showEvent(QShowEvent *)` and add the file there. That method is executed when the widget is about to be show.

Comment: I doubt the same thing.But the another addFile execute use the copy file after this executed cost 0ms.So I think Qt is setting some environment context and that cost much time.And, if I use QIcon::addPixmap(QPixmap("fileName")) instead QIcon::addFile, the cost time is 0ms.I read the document, addFile function auto load file when the file's name contains '@2x', add QPixmap init doesn't auto load.So I think the the differences between addFile and addPixmap is setting something to auto load files.